# http://notifications.newsdoses.com/ I want to change the main color on hover

Tags: menu, menu-item

http://notifications.newsdoses.com/ I want to change the main color on hover from green to orange. I'm using jd _Atlanta template. Please help! I tried but unable to do that.
ps latest joomla version.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the CSS for the hover :

```
.gf-menu li:hover > .item{
       color:orange;
    }
```

I don't know if that work directly, because of your media queries in your current CSS. 
( *@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px)* )

This is btw. not a Joomla related question.

Comment: not working. can you specify in which .css file? because I cannot find custom.css file which should be present.

Comment: I don't know your template, you should check their forum or documentation. You can add you own css files into the index.php of the template just add your custom.css to the html-head like they did with  "responsive.css" , then create you custom.css and write you overrides. Just check their css selectors with you browsers dev tools and override it.

Comment: You are welcome, if possible can you set my answer the correct answer to your question or at least give an upvote? thanks.